# How to print items through two for loops in Java

Tags: java, csv, for-loop

My goal is to print my outputs separately and each on a new line. I have two for loops one nested inside the other and have it removing the first input but it doubles every output when printed. My code is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\o.csv\\"));
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = br.readLine();
line = br.readLine();
while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    lines.add(line);
    line = br.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String[] lineItemsArr = {};

        lineItemsArr = lines.get(i).split(",");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lineItemsArr));
        list.remove(0);
        lineItemsArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        // list.clear();
        //lineItemsArr = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < lineItemsArr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(lineItemsArr[j]);

        }
    }
}
```

So if my csv has : 3333, May14, 0003, May5 I want it to print each separately but instead it is printing each row twice so if May 5 is the next row It is printing:

> 3333 May14 003 3333 May14 003 may5

Comment: Hello, why don't you use BeanIO ? http://beanio.org/

Comment: I rather not use external libraries I tried OpenCsv but kept getting errors and difficulties

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you need 2 loops.However it would seem you need to move ` ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();` to be inside the outer loop.

Comment: That did the trick thank you so much I didn't even notice that

Comment: @val at some point you'll **need** to get comfortable with external libraries. This is one of the first things I've been taught at university, but I didn't want to believe it immediately. Use code that has already been heavily tested!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and fix the issue with the below code snippet. As mentioned by [Alan Hay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356423/alan-hay) above the issue stems from the lines Array.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\o.csv\\"));

String line = br.readLine(); //Reading and ignoring first line

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    String[] lineItemsArr = line.split(",");

    for (String s : lineItemsArr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You think to complicated.

```
  // "C:\\Users\\o.csv\\" double backslash would mean o.csv is a dir
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\o.csv")); 
  ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
  // a for loop is perfectly suited to do initialization, 
  // incrementation and checking for break condition    
  for (String line = br.readLine (); line !=null && !line.isEmpty (); line = br.readLine ())
  {
      // is lines really needed? 
      lines.add (line); // really needed?
      // there is no reason, to initialize lineItemsArr first 
      // to an empty array. 
      String [] lineItemsArr = line.split (",");
      // in many cases, a simplified for loop is better suited than index iteration
      for (String lineItem : lineItemsArr)
      {
          System.out.println (lineItem);
      }
  }
```

To supress the first element, use:

```
String[] from2nd =  Arrays.copyOfRange (lineItemsArr, 1, lineItemsArr.length);
```

So in context:

```
      String [] lineItemsArr = line.split (",");
      String[] from2nd =  Arrays.copyOfRange (lineItemsArr, 1, lineItemsArr.length);
      for (String lineItem : from2nd)
      {
          System.out.println (lineItem);
      }
```

or shorter

```
      String [] lineItemsArr = line.split (",");
      for (String lineItem : Arrays.copyOfRange (lineItemsArr, 1, lineItemsArr.length))
      {
          System.out.println (lineItem);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand your code does ;
At each line read, it prints every lines read values, except the first value of each line.

What you can do to print only one time each field:

**Print after reading all lines**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\o.csv\\"));
List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = br.readLine();
line = br.readLine();
while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
    items.remove(0);
    lines.add(items);
    line = br.readLine();
}
for (List<String> items: lines) {
    for (String item: items) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

**Print only the fields of the current line**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\o.csv\\"));
List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = br.readLine();
line = br.readLine();
while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
    items.remove(0);
    for (String item: items) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
    lines.add(items);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

In this case, if you don't need lines after reading, you can remove this variable, see @ggolding's response for this case.